# -su: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to follow [google cloud tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/gce-tutorial/) to work on [cs231n](http://cs231) assignments. After some trials and errors I have finally managed to use **Compute Engine - GCE with putty** explained [here](https://gist.github.com/feczo/7282a6e00181fde4281b). Now I need to perform

```
./<DIRECTORY-WHERE-GOOGLE-CLOUD-IS-INSTALLED>/bin/gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-west1-b <YOUR-INSTANCE-NAME>
```

step from [google cloud tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/gce-tutorial/). The directory where google cloud is installed is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin`. 
When I hit enter it shows the error:

```
-su: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

People suggest putting `/` or `` ` `` sign before each parenthesis. As I expect, it didn't work.
I could not find any particular topic on this very problem so I thought I should post it right away.
If anyone can help, it would be appreciated much.

Edit: I am on Windows 7 Professional, x64. But my instance on cloud Engine is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What OS are you running this on? Please add this vital information to your question by [edit]ing it.